# What can cause higher CPU time and duration for a given set of queries in trace(s) ran on two separate environments?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm troubleshooting a performance issue in a SQL Server DR environment for a customer. They are running queries that consistently take longer in their environment than our QA environment. After analyzing traces that were performed in both environments with the same parameters/filters and with the same version of SQL Server (2016 SP2) and the exact same database, we observed that both environment were picking the same execution plan(s) for the queries in question, and the number of reads/writes were close in both environments, however the total duration of the process in question and the CPU time logged in the trace were significantly higher in the customer environment. Duration of all processes in our QA environment was around 18 seconds, the customer was over 80 seconds, our CPU time was close to 10 seconds, theirs was also over 80 seconds. Also worth mentioning, both environments are currently configured to MAXDOP 1.

The customer has less memory (~100GB vs 120GB), and slower disks (10k HHD vs SSD) than our QA environment, but but more CPUs. Both environments are dedicated to this activity and should have little/no external load that wouldn't match. I don't have all the details on CPU architecture they are using, waiting for some of that information now. The customer has confirmed they have excluded SQL Server and the data/log files from their virus scanning. Obviously there could be a ton of issues in the hardware configuration.

I'm currently waiting to see a recent snapshot of their wait stats and system DMVs, the data we originally received, didn't appear to have any major CPU, memory or Disk latency pressure. I recently asked them to check to see if the windows power setting was in performance or balanced mode, however I'm not certain that would have the impact we're seeing or not if the CPUs were being throttled.

My question is, what factors can affect CPU time and ultimately total duration? Is CPU time, as shown in a sql trace, based primarily on the speed of the processors or are their other factors I should be taking in to consideration. The fact that both are generating the same query plans and all other things being as close as possible to equal, makes me think it's related to the hardware SQL is installed on.

Comment: Did you check index fragmentation and statistics? It is probably there is a different rows estimation on your execution plan. Also, can you share your execution plans with https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ , so we can take more information for helping you.

Comment: thanks for bringing that up, they initially did appear to have out of date stats, reads were much higher prior to the stats update we did, but after stats update, reads were much closer to ours, but CPU/duration were still as outlined above.  I wish I could share more about the plan, but not currently at the liberty to do so.

Comment: Same SQL Server Edition (Enterpsrise, Standard?)

Comment: Have you compared sys.configurations?

Answer (score 1):

That production has more CPUs does not matter when you use MaxDOP 1. Then only CPU Clock cycle matters. With many CPUs, you often get lower 1.x GHz clock cycle. A higher clock cycle on your QA could explain some of the difference.

If the database cannot fit into memory, then your hard disk speed difference sounds as if it alone can explain the different duration time.

May I recommend that you install the First Responder Kit from Brent Ozar?
https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/
This will alert you to the most obvious problems.

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the frequency of the CPUs?

Lower frequency will take longer to execute the given statement(s) which will result in longer duration when querying the data. The retrieval of the requested data is then down to the throughput (I/O) of the underlying hardware.

#### What happens if you/they run the query twice?

One the data is in memory, it shoudn't take that much longer to query the data again. However, if they have less memory, then it could be that the data being retrieved does not fit into memory. Then it has to be retrieved from disk.

#### What Editions are being used?

Enterprise can read up to multiple MB of data when performing read-aheads of large data sets. You're probably running Developer Edition which is basically Enterprise Edition. They might be using Standard Edition. This can result in less data being read in advance when querying and returning large data sets.

Microsoft lists this under the features as **Read-Ahead** in the [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15) in the [**RDBMS Scalability and Performance**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSSP) section

```
Feature    | Enterprise | Standard | Web | Express with Advanced Services | Express
-----------+------------+----------+-----+--------------------------------+---------
Read-Ahead | Yes        | No       | No  | No                             | No
```

#### In General

If the execution plans are the same, then it's basically down to finding the differences in hardware, SAN infrastructure and possibly SQL Server Editions.

#### Wait Statistics

If you run this query from Paul Randal [Capturing wait statistics for a period of time](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-statistics-period-time/) and run the first part of Paul's query, then your statement, and then the second part of Paul's query, then it will tell you what is was waiting for during the execution of the script.

```
/*============================================================================
  File:     ShortPeriodWaitStats.sql
  
  Summary:  Short snapshot of wait stats
  
  SQL Server Versions: 2005 onwards
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Written by Paul S. Randal, SQLskills.com
  
  (c) 2018, SQLskills.com. All rights reserved.
 
  Last update 9/25/2018
  
  For more scripts and sample code, check out http://www.SQLskills.com
  
  You may alter this code for your own *non-commercial* purposes (e.g. in a
  for-sale commercial tool). Use in your own environment is encouraged.
  You may republish altered code as long as you include this copyright and
  give due credit, but you must obtain prior permission before blogging
  this code.
  
  THIS CODE AND INFORMATION ARE PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
  ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
  TO THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
  PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
============================================================================*/
  
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[sys].[objects]
    WHERE [name] = N'##SQLskillsStats1')
    DROP TABLE [##SQLskillsStats1];
  
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[sys].[objects]
    WHERE [name] = N'##SQLskillsStats2')
    DROP TABLE [##SQLskillsStats2];
GO
  
SELECT [wait_type], [waiting_tasks_count], [wait_time_ms],
       [max_wait_time_ms], [signal_wait_time_ms]
INTO ##SQLskillsStats1
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats;
GO
```

Ommit the `WAIT FOR ...` bit and run your query instead in a different query window, then run:

```
SELECT [wait_type], [waiting_tasks_count], [wait_time_ms],
       [max_wait_time_ms], [signal_wait_time_ms]
INTO ##SQLskillsStats2
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats;
GO
  
WITH [DiffWaits] AS
(SELECT
-- Waits that weren't in the first snapshot
        [ts2].[wait_type],
        [ts2].[wait_time_ms],
        [ts2].[signal_wait_time_ms],
        [ts2].[waiting_tasks_count]
    FROM [##SQLskillsStats2] AS [ts2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [##SQLskillsStats1] AS [ts1]
        ON [ts2].[wait_type] = [ts1].[wait_type]
    WHERE [ts1].[wait_type] IS NULL
    AND [ts2].[wait_time_ms] > 0
UNION
SELECT
-- Diff of waits in both snapshots
        [ts2].[wait_type],
        [ts2].[wait_time_ms] - [ts1].[wait_time_ms] AS [wait_time_ms],
        [ts2].[signal_wait_time_ms] - [ts1].[signal_wait_time_ms] AS [signal_wait_time_ms],
        [ts2].[waiting_tasks_count] - [ts1].[waiting_tasks_count] AS [waiting_tasks_count]
    FROM [##SQLskillsStats2] AS [ts2]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [##SQLskillsStats1] AS [ts1]
        ON [ts2].[wait_type] = [ts1].[wait_type]
    WHERE [ts1].[wait_type] IS NOT NULL
    AND [ts2].[waiting_tasks_count] - [ts1].[waiting_tasks_count] > 0
    AND [ts2].[wait_time_ms] - [ts1].[wait_time_ms] > 0),
[Waits] AS
    (SELECT
        [wait_type],
        [wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [WaitS],
        ([wait_time_ms] - [signal_wait_time_ms]) / 1000.0 AS [ResourceS],
        [signal_wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [SignalS],
        [waiting_tasks_count] AS [WaitCount],
        100.0 * [wait_time_ms] / SUM ([wait_time_ms]) OVER() AS [Percentage],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [wait_time_ms] DESC) AS [RowNum]
    FROM [DiffWaits]
    WHERE [wait_type] NOT IN (
        -- These wait types are almost 100% never a problem and so they are
        -- filtered out to avoid them skewing the results. Click on the URL
        -- for more information.
        N'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/BROKER_EVENTHANDLER
        N'BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR
        N'BROKER_TASK_STOP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/BROKER_TASK_STOP
        N'BROKER_TO_FLUSH', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/BROKER_TO_FLUSH
        N'BROKER_TRANSMITTER', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/BROKER_TRANSMITTER
        N'CHECKPOINT_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/CHECKPOINT_QUEUE
        N'CHKPT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/CHKPT
        N'CLR_AUTO_EVENT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/CLR_AUTO_EVENT
        N'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/CLR_MANUAL_EVENT
        N'CLR_SEMAPHORE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/CLR_SEMAPHORE
        N'CXCONSUMER', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/CXCONSUMER
 
        -- Maybe comment these four out if you have mirroring issues
        N'DBMIRROR_DBM_EVENT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/DBMIRROR_DBM_EVENT
        N'DBMIRROR_EVENTS_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/DBMIRROR_EVENTS_QUEUE
        N'DBMIRROR_WORKER_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/DBMIRROR_WORKER_QUEUE
        N'DBMIRRORING_CMD', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/DBMIRRORING_CMD
 
        N'DIRTY_PAGE_POLL', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/DIRTY_PAGE_POLL
        N'DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE
        N'EXECSYNC', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/EXECSYNC
        N'FSAGENT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/FSAGENT
        N'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT
        N'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX
 
        -- Maybe comment these six out if you have AG issues
        N'HADR_CLUSAPI_CALL', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/HADR_CLUSAPI_CALL
        N'HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION
        N'HADR_LOGCAPTURE_WAIT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/HADR_LOGCAPTURE_WAIT
        N'HADR_NOTIFICATION_DEQUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/HADR_NOTIFICATION_DEQUEUE
        N'HADR_TIMER_TASK', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/HADR_TIMER_TASK
        N'HADR_WORK_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/HADR_WORK_QUEUE
 
        N'KSOURCE_WAKEUP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/KSOURCE_WAKEUP
        N'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/LAZYWRITER_SLEEP
        N'LOGMGR_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/LOGMGR_QUEUE
        N'MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT
        N'ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE
        N'PARALLEL_REDO_DRAIN_WORKER', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PARALLEL_REDO_DRAIN_WORKER
        N'PARALLEL_REDO_LOG_CACHE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PARALLEL_REDO_LOG_CACHE
        N'PARALLEL_REDO_TRAN_LIST', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PARALLEL_REDO_TRAN_LIST
        N'PARALLEL_REDO_WORKER_SYNC', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PARALLEL_REDO_WORKER_SYNC
        N'PARALLEL_REDO_WORKER_WAIT_WORK', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PARALLEL_REDO_WORKER_WAIT_WORK
        N'PREEMPTIVE_XE_GETTARGETSTATE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PREEMPTIVE_XE_GETTARGETSTATE
        N'PWAIT_ALL_COMPONENTS_INITIALIZED', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PWAIT_ALL_COMPONENTS_INITIALIZED
        N'PWAIT_DIRECTLOGCONSUMER_GETNEXT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PWAIT_DIRECTLOGCONSUMER_GETNEXT
        N'QDS_PERSIST_TASK_MAIN_LOOP_SLEEP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/QDS_PERSIST_TASK_MAIN_LOOP_SLEEP
        N'QDS_ASYNC_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/QDS_ASYNC_QUEUE
        N'QDS_CLEANUP_STALE_QUERIES_TASK_MAIN_LOOP_SLEEP',
            -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/QDS_CLEANUP_STALE_QUERIES_TASK_MAIN_LOOP_SLEEP
        N'QDS_SHUTDOWN_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/QDS_SHUTDOWN_QUEUE
        N'REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/REDO_THREAD_PENDING_WORK
        N'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH
        N'RESOURCE_QUEUE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/RESOURCE_QUEUE
        N'SERVER_IDLE_CHECK', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SERVER_IDLE_CHECK
        N'SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH
        N'SLEEP_DBSTARTUP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_DBSTARTUP
        N'SLEEP_DCOMSTARTUP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_DCOMSTARTUP
        N'SLEEP_MASTERDBREADY', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_MASTERDBREADY
        N'SLEEP_MASTERMDREADY', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_MASTERMDREADY
        N'SLEEP_MASTERUPGRADED', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_MASTERUPGRADED
        N'SLEEP_MSDBSTARTUP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_MSDBSTARTUP
        N'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK
        N'SLEEP_TASK', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_TASK
        N'SLEEP_TEMPDBSTARTUP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SLEEP_TEMPDBSTARTUP
        N'SNI_HTTP_ACCEPT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SNI_HTTP_ACCEPT
        N'SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER
        N'SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP
        N'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH
        N'SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP
        N'SQLTRACE_WAIT_ENTRIES', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SQLTRACE_WAIT_ENTRIES
        N'WAIT_FOR_RESULTS', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WAIT_FOR_RESULTS
        N'WAITFOR', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WAITFOR
        N'WAITFOR_TASKSHUTDOWN', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WAITFOR_TASKSHUTDOWN
        N'WAIT_XTP_RECOVERY', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WAIT_XTP_RECOVERY
        N'WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT
        N'WAIT_XTP_OFFLINE_CKPT_NEW_LOG', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WAIT_XTP_OFFLINE_CKPT_NEW_LOG
        N'WAIT_XTP_CKPT_CLOSE', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WAIT_XTP_CKPT_CLOSE
        N'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN
        N'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT', -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT
        N'XE_TIMER_EVENT' -- https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/XE_TIMER_EVENT
    )
    )
SELECT
    [W1].[wait_type] AS [WaitType],
    CAST ([W1].[WaitS] AS DECIMAL (16, 2)) AS [Wait_S],
    CAST ([W1].[ResourceS] AS DECIMAL (16, 2)) AS [Resource_S],
    CAST ([W1].[SignalS] AS DECIMAL (16, 2)) AS [Signal_S],
    [W1].[WaitCount] AS [WaitCount],
    CAST ([W1].[Percentage] AS DECIMAL (5, 2)) AS [Percentage],
    CAST (([W1].[WaitS] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (16, 4)) AS [AvgWait_S],
    CAST (([W1].[ResourceS] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (16, 4)) AS [AvgRes_S],
    CAST (([W1].[SignalS] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (16, 4)) AS [AvgSig_S],
    CAST ('https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/' + MAX ([W1].[wait_type]) as XML) AS [Help/Info URL]
FROM [Waits] AS [W1]
INNER JOIN [Waits] AS [W2]
    ON [W2].[RowNum] <= [W1].[RowNum]
GROUP BY [W1].[RowNum], [W1].[wait_type], [W1].[WaitS],
    [W1].[ResourceS], [W1].[SignalS], [W1].[WaitCount], [W1].[Percentage]
HAVING SUM ([W2].[Percentage]) - [W1].[Percentage] < 95; -- percentage threshold
GO
  
-- Cleanup
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[sys].[objects]
    WHERE [name] = N'##SQLskillsStats1')
    DROP TABLE [##SQLskillsStats1];
  
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[sys].[objects]
    WHERE [name] = N'##SQLskillsStats2')
    DROP TABLE [##SQLskillsStats2];
GO
```

You'll then receive a list of waits that look like this:

```
+----------------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|    WaitType    | Wait_S | Resource_S | Signal_S | WaitCount | Percentage | AvgWait_S | AvgRes_S | AvgSig_S |                    Help/Info URL                    |
+----------------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| WRITELOG       |   0.25 |       0.24 |     0.01 |       251 |      89.29 |    0.0010 |   0.0010 |   0.0000 | https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/WRITELOG       |
| PAGELATCH_SH   |   0.01 |       0.00 |     0.01 |        46 |       4.29 |    0.0003 |   0.0000 |   0.0003 | https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PAGELATCH_SH   |
| PAGEIOLATCH_EX |   0.01 |       0.01 |     0.00 |         3 |       3.21 |    0.0030 |   0.0030 |   0.0000 | https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/PAGEIOLATCH_EX |
+----------------+--------+------------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

You can then click on the links to see what the SQL Server was waiting for.